# How to read a XML file with SQL Server and AWS RSD?

Tags: sql-server, xml, amazon-web-services

I have a database on AWS RSD, I have a basic account of AWS. I found that I have to store the XML file on internet, then I have to read it from the URL.

So, I store the XML file into a Github repository and then I execute the query below. On my local server I have to execute a RECONFIG to activate some permissions.

It worked well on my local server, but in my database in AWS it didn't work. It prints a error of permissions of `sp_OACreate, sp_OAMethod, sp_OAGetProperty, sp_OADestroy`. Also I don't have permissions to execute `sp_configure` and `RECONFIGURE`.

I tried to change setting in the server page but I didn't found anything.

```
DECLARE    
    @url VARCHAR(1000),
    @url2 VARCHAR(300),
    @win INT,
    @hr INT,
    @Text VARCHAR(4000),
    @xml XML

SET @url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KevinFallas03/FacturacionMunicipal_BD/master/Base%20de%20Datos/XML/Administradores.xml'--current file
SET @url2 = 'http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml'--test file

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @win OUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText', @Text OUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @win 
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

SELECT @Text

SET @xml=CAST(@Text AS XML)
SELECT @xml
```

Query to activate permissions, it works on local database:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

My intention is read a XML file from my database in AWS. So, if there is another way to do it, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

RDS offers many different types of database. It looks like you are using Microsoft SQL Server.

RDS is a *managed* database service. That means that you do not have full admin permissions on the database. You seem to be hoping to use OLE Automation, which requires the use of certain Stored Procedures like `sp_OACreate`.

OLE Automation is **not** supported in RDS Microsoft SQL Server. One alternative is to install and manage your own [MS SQL Server running on EC2](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/best-practices-for-deploying-microsoft-sql-server-on-aws.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

One option to solve the problem is to create a bucket on Amazon Storage S3, then upload the XML file on the bucket. Next you have to integrate AWS S3 buckets with AWS RDS SQL Server.

For complete guide to integrate AWS S3 buckets with AWS RDS SQL Server consulte here: https://www.sqlshack.com/integrating-aws-s3-buckets-with-aws-rds-sql-server/

With all set you can download the XML file with:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.rds_download_from_s3
 @s3_arn_of_file = 'arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/<xml-name>.xml', --string with the ARN
 @rds_file_path = 'D:\S3\<storage-name>\<xml-name>.xml', --where xml is saved
 @overwrite_file = 1;
```

To check the status of the previuos task:

```
EXEC msdb..rds_task_status @task_id = <task_number>;
```

To parse the XML file:

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\S3\<storage-name>\<xml-name>.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```